# Bootstrap 4.1.3 modal body retains jquery returned data. How to clear cache for each new request?

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.7

I have a form that submits data via jquery which is then shown via bootstrap modal.

However, the problem is that, if I quickly try to give new values to the form then the modal body sometimes doesn't show freshly calculated values but shows the old cached values.

How can I destroy the modal cache data in bootstrap 4 ? I have tried various bootstrap3 tips but it just wouldn't work and I still see old cached data intermittantly.

Here is what I tried.

```
  $('#modalForm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#modal_content').empty();
      $('#modalForm').modal('dispose');
      $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
      $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
      //$('.modal').remove(); // this prevents future modals
  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code to populate or create the modal?

Comment: can you check if your form does not contain an element with name="reset". Reset function will not work in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a binding issue, you are binding `hidden.bs.modal` on the `#modalForm` so unless you don't unbind it at some point, the same code will always execute with old values.

Try unbinding it by putting this code `$('#modalForm').off('hidden.bs.modal')` right before `$('#modalForm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {[...]` and if it doesn't work you might want to bind it only once using the `$('#modalForm').one('hidden.bs.modal')` instead.