# Jquery Modal causes double trigger when closed and reopened

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my modal:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("submit","#modal",function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveRole", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                method: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $(document).off("submit");
                        $("#close").trigger("click");
                        return;
                    }
                    $.each(result.errors, function (index, item) {
                        // Get message placeholder
                        var element = $('[data-valmsg-for="' + item.propertyName + '"]');
                        element.empty();
                        // Update message
                        element.append($('<span></span>').text(item.errorMessage));
                        // Update class names
                        element.removeClass('field-validation-valid').addClass('field-validation-error');
                        $('#' + item.propertyName).removeClass('valid').addClass('input-validation-error');
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    @if (Model.Id == null)
    {
        <h2>Add Role</h2>
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>Edit Role</h2>
    }
    <hr />
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "modal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ApplicationId)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RoleName, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RoleName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            <a href="#" id="close" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" rel="modal:close">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What happens is that when I submit the form in this modal, it populates a table when it closes. However, when I open the modal and immediately close it, open it again and submit the form, 2 entries get populated into the table. I tried to remove the click event handler in the modal but it still happens.

This is what I do when the modal is closed:

```
$(document).off($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE);
$(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
    table.draw();
    $("#modal").empty();
    $("#modal").off();
    $("#model").dialog('destroy');
});
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

This is how I open my modal:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "RoleDetails", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { Id = "", ApplicationId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @rel = "modal:open" })
```

EDIT2:

I checked if theres a click even on my button but it shows no click event even when i close the modal before submitting it:

```
if (buttonEvent && buttonEvent.click) {
   console.log("Has Click Event");
} else {
   console.log("No Click Event");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4.1.3 modal body retains jquery returned data. How to clear cache for each new request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56136200/bootstrap-4-1-3-modal-body-retains-jquery-returned-data-how-to-clear-cache-for)

Comment: try this $("#model").dialog('destroy');

Comment: Tried to destroy it as well. Doesn't work. I tried the off function but I dont have a hidden.bs.modal to destroy?

Comment: @JianYA : please watch the answer I provided on the link in my first comment

Comment: I tried your answer. I am unable to use .one because of the jquery modal i'm using. I've edited my question to show how I call the modal

Comment: You don't need to use $.one, try `$(document).off($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE)` right before your `$(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE)` call.

Comment: Also remove `$("#save").off("submit"); $("#save").off("click");`.

Comment: Is like how I have edited my question? I tried that and its still doing the double trigger. I made sure to clear my cache as well but its still the same.